# On click event, change input field in a sibling component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to detect a click in a child component. In its sibling component, I want to empty out the input field within it. Let me show you a brief example of what I mean:

```
// Parent component template:
<div>
  <child1-comp></child1-comp>
  <child2-comp></child2-comp>
</div>
```

.

```
// child1-comp template:
<input type="text" #inputText (keyup)="0">
```

.

```
// child2-comp template:
<ul>
  <li (click)="onClick(text1.value)" #text1>Test</li>
  <li (click)="onClick(text2.value)" #text2>Test2</li>
</ul>
```

After one of the click events in `child2-comp`, I want to empty out the value in the input field in `child1-comp`.

Is this possible to do in Angular 2?

Comment: There are several options, check official cookbook, chapter [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) for examples.

Comment: @Sasxa What I tried doing is using an eventemitter from `child2` and it would just emit a boolean value. In the parent, I grabbed the `$event` and stored it in a variable. This variable is then passed to `child1`. I tried using `*ngIf` but i'm getting a template issue. Am I on the right track? Or should I look for another approach?

Comment: Can you create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5) with your setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
// Parent component template:
<div>
  <child1-comp [(value)]="value"></child1-comp>
  <child2-comp (click)="value=''"></child2-comp>
</div>
```

.

```
// child1-comp template:
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (keyup)="0">
```

.

```
// child2-comp template:
<ul>
  <li (click)="click.emit(text1.value)" #text1>Test</li>
  <li (click)="click.emit(text2.value)" #text2>Test2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about using `Observable` via `rxjs`? Any suggestion and elegant example for that?

Answer (score 3):

**Component to component communication via serivce**

when the component are not in the parent child relationship,just create and service make them communicate each other, Once you create the service you can call or reroute the call using  subscriber.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class MissionService {
  // Observable string sources
  private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();
  // Observable string streams
  missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
  }
  confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
    this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
  }
}


import { Component }          from '@angular/core';
import { MissionService }     from './mission.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'mission-control',
  template: `
    <h2>Mission Control</h2>
    <button (click)="announce()">Announce mission</button>
    <my-astronaut *ngFor="let astronaut of astronauts"
      [astronaut]="astronaut">
    </my-astronaut>
    <h3>History</h3>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let event of history">{{event}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers: [MissionService]
})
export class MissionControlComponent {
  astronauts = ['Lovell', 'Swigert', 'Haise'];
  history: string[] = [];
  missions = ['Fly to the moon!',
              'Fly to mars!',
              'Fly to Vegas!'];
  nextMission = 0;
  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    missionService.missionConfirmed$.subscribe(
      astronaut => {
        this.history.push(`${astronaut} confirmed the mission`);
      });
  }
  announce() {
    let mission = this.missions[this.nextMission++];
    this.missionService.announceMission(mission);
    this.history.push(`Mission "${mission}" announced`);
    if (this.nextMission >= this.missions.length) { this.nextMission = 0; }
  }
}



import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MissionService } from './mission.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-astronaut',
  template: `
    <p>
      {{astronaut}}: <strong>{{mission}}</strong>
      <button
        (click)="confirm()"
        [disabled]="!announced || confirmed">
        Confirm
      </button>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AstronautComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input() astronaut: string;
  mission = '<no mission announced>';
  confirmed = false;
  announced = false;
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    this.subscription = missionService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
      mission => {
        this.mission = mission;
        this.announced = true;
        this.confirmed = false;
    });
  }
  confirm() {
    this.confirmed = true;
    this.missionService.confirmMission(this.astronaut);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: is this still the acceptable technique? Even for Angular 6?